# How to set up reverse-proxy to an external server in IIS

Tags: iis, reverse-proxy, rewrite

So the scenario we have in mind is as follows.

We have an IFRAME. Said IFRAME wants to point to a resource on `https://trees.com`. It might be, for example, `https://trees.com/ficus/macrophylla`. However, despite all our requests to `trees.com`, they refuse to allow us to link directly to their site, blocking the cross-origin request.

So we decide we want to set up a reverse-proxy. We've heard about nginx and apache but we've got a corporate commitment to Microsoft's technology, for better or worse, so decide in favour of IIS.

Using one of our Azure servers, we create a website, let's call it `https://figs.wild.com.au`. We configure the IFRAMEs so that a request to `https://trees.com/ficus/macrophylla` actually goes to `https://figs.wild.com.au/trees/ficus/macrophylla`.

At this point we go slightly insane.

Is it actually possible for the request `https://figs.wild.com.au/trees/ficus/macrophylla` to be converted, on the `figs.wild.com.au` server, to a request for `https://trees.com/ficus/macrophylla` and for the response to that to be fed back to the originator of the IFRAME request?

We've done a lot of searching and we keep finding things that *almost* work. What actually does work? Is IIS's Url Rewrite the thing to use, and if so, what should the rule/s look like? Or should we be using some C#-y thing instead?

Comment: How are you determining `they refuse to allow us to link directly to their site, blocking the cross-origin request`?

Comment: Is the content from `https://trees.com/` static?

Comment: The initial part should be possible with the modules [Microsoft Application Request Routing](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=47333) and [URL Rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite). The other not so sure but I'm visualizing as working in a similar way to Try Except blocks in Python. Basically if possible, it would save that response to a file or something and then you could use that file to feed the IFRAME.

Comment: Again, the initial two questions are relevant because you might as well request the data from the pages, save it it a file with a specific name and use that file for the IFRAMEs. While that might sound as extra work, it's possible and can be automated.

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁 ARR and URL Rewrite are very likely the answer. I just don't get how URL Rewrite rules work (yet) so I'm rather hoping someone tells me the answer rather than pointing in some general direction.

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁 I wrote about [a related issue](https://serverfault.com/questions/1025415/trying-to-understand-reverse-proxying-using-nginx-and-windows-iis) and was rather hoping Lex Li would be more forthcoming

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁 So if you've got how to do this in nginx sorted, I'd be happy with that

Answer (score 1):

If I go to http://www.trees.com/ficus/macrophylla using the browser, then will get

[image: not found]

If I go to http://www.trees.com/ will also get the following

[image: Not sure if that's how it should look like]

---

Using SSL Request to trees.com

[image: SSL Request]

Clicking "Click here to ignore the mismatch...", will then get

[image: SSL Request trees.com]

In the configuration,

[image: SSL Request configuration]

we can see TLS 1.0, 1.1, 1.2 and 1.3 are supported. Yet, green color for TLS 1.2 and 1.3.

We can configure PowerShell to use TLS 1.3

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls13
```

And confirm it will be using it

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol
```

[image: TLS13 PowerShell]

---

In PowerShell (as Administrator), if one uses [Invoke-WebRequest](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-5.1)

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri trees.com/ficus/macrophylla
```

then will get

[image: 404 not found]

and if one uses

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri trees.com
```

then will get

[image: it worked]

---

So far so good. But if we want to test it for CORS from the https://figs.wild.com.au,

```
(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://trees.com' -Headers @{ "Origin" = "https://figs.wild.com.au" }).Headers
```

we get

```
Key                           Value
---                           -----
Transfer-Encoding             chunked
X-Adblock-Key                 MFwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADSwAwSAJBAL/3/SrV7P8AsTHMFSpPmYbyv2PkACHwmG9Z+1IFZq3vA54IN7pQcGnhgNo+8SN9r/KtUWCb9OPqTfWM1N4w/EUCAwEAAQ==_FamzgofQ7ugTniHINrZ7yp35i/Nqkt7q/gZsgPGyvhOwIQhj04Bd9+/nir6OLAFDPB56kU4m0GgS7SvEoFqRbQ==
Access-Control-Allow-Origin   *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods  *
Access-Control-Request-Method *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers  *
Access-Control-Max-Age        86400
X-UA-Compatible               IE=Edge,chrome=1
X-Request-Id                  556905ec3cb435a1168cc1b28d70875f
X-Runtime                     0.048014
X-Rack-Cache                  miss
Cache-Control                 max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Content-Type                  text/html; charset=utf-8
Date                          Mon, 20 Jul 2020 09:40:37 GMT
ETag                          "8e51e434b70033ee6a90cb7397af53f9"
Set-Cookie                    _digiadmin2_session=BAh7B0kiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFVEkiJTNmOWRlMDA5NjRiZWZlMzgyZTRmN2NlOWIzZmQxZjIzBjsAVEkiEF9jc3JmX3Rva2VuBjsARkkiMVFOckhMdElRMWc1cGZBcGl5OGQ1WkVNeXo3elpobWRwc2QyR0djTFlNUEE9BjsARg%3D%3D--e55261be794bb9f95ee407c73a3e2b315ef...
Server                        nginx/1.10.1
```

[image: Headers key Value]

Notice that **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** has the value **asterisk (*)** which means that any domain is allowed. Then, if we use the following command

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://trees.com' -Headers @{ "Origin" = "https://figs.wild.com.au" }
```

we will get the following result

[image: As expected]

---

In other words, it's allowing cross-origin request and not blocking like you're mentioning in the question. Could be that you're giving fictitious URLs too just for the sake of the explanation.

Comment: I am most definitely "giving fictitious URLs ...just for the sake of the explanation". I always do.

Comment: So you confirm the «Access-Control-Allow-Origin» doesn't include the asterisk?

Answer (score 1):

In regards to the question and considering the comments, redirection to an external URL is possible in IIS as [shown here](https://forums.iis.net/t/1230389.aspx?Forward%20to%20external%20website).

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="External Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^VirtualDirectory" negate="true" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" pattern="hostname"/>
          <!-- add this input condotion to make this redirect url not work with http://hostname/VirtualDirectory -->
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="{your url}" redirectType="Found" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Also, a simple redirect is possible using NGIX and is addressed, for instances, [in this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/502115/405578).

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name     example.com;
    return          301 http://www.example.com$request_uri;

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name     www.example.com;
    [...]
```

and [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11815374/5675325)

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name localhost;
  merge_slashes off;

  location /rdr {
    location /rdr/http:// {
      rewrite ^/rdr/(.*)$ $1 permanent;
    }
    rewrite ^/rdr/(.*)$ http://$1 permanent;
  }
}
```

Yet, what you want isn't to see the content of that page but to save that data anywhere and then redirect again. Where will that data be coming from then to feed the IFRAME?

---

Instead of doing this `redirect > save data > redirect`, I would suggest to do that separately. More specifically, you'd get the data from https://trees.com/ficus/macrophylla and save it in the location of https://figs.wild.com.au/trees/ficus/macrophylla and use what you want from that file for the IFRAMEs.

To get the content of the file in the location https://trees.com (without JS and CSS coming from other files) and save it in an html file, you'd do something like

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
html = urlopen("http://trees.com").read().decode('utf-8')
#print(html)
with open("test.html", "w") as file:
    file.write(html)
```

This will save the content in an HTML file named test present in the same location of this script.

(If CSS and JS is also required, do check [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31205497/5675325)).

If you don't want to go through that hustle, there's tools like [HTTrack](https://www.httrack.com/) that allow to download complete websites. This way you wouldn't need to know the mapsite to then iterate over the possible variations.

---

I can see the convenience of what you want. Will investigate further and let you know if find that *super-automated* way to do this but would help to know "Where will that data be coming from then to feed the IFRAME?".